# How to block usage of DateTime.parse() from coders on VisualStudio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overriding

We want our coders to NOT use `DateTime.parse()`.
How can we block to use it?
Can we override this, to hide from them?

**EDIT1**
Actually we want to override this method, we have our own method which gets called this way: `clsStrUtils.ISOToDate()`.

**EDIT2**

We do trust our programmers, but this is a specific situation. I don't want to restrict no-one using a better way, I just want to restrict Parse(). They can still use **ParseExact()**.

Comment: Do you just not trust your programming staff?

Comment: So is your question essentially, "How can I hijack the .Net framework and replace one of its static methods?" I hope the answer is "You can't."

Comment: we all really want to know why you want to do this - please tell

Comment: We want to force them to use something else.

Comment: `clsStrUtils` -- that name just makes me cringe and brings back some nasty VB6 memories...  If you're using .Net 3.5 (or 4.0), take a look at Extension Methods.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Set a code-review policy up and have all version-control commits logged to the user.  Keep an audit trail of who reviews who's code.  If one ever turns up, you throw the person who wrote the code into a fiery furnace and flay the code reviewer with a bunch of sharp pointy sticks.

Comment: Too much time lost to behave like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to write a custom rule in FxCop to do this. [Check out the tutorials on this site](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html) for information on how. You then might be able to run it periodically to validate that the members of the team are using the standards you put in place.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a continuous integration system?  If you do, you could mark a build as failed if a style check check does not pass.  Make sure to scan for references to "DateTime.Parse" in your style check.

A better solution would be to unit test your code.   DateTime.Parse has plenty of valid uses, and it might be better to just make sure tests cover them.

Comment: We want to force them to use something else.

Comment: If there are cases that your ISOToDate() method covers that DateTime.Parse() does not, make sure those are represented in tests, then.  Other than that style checking is the only solution I can think of.  There shouldn't be a way to do it during development time, unless you want to hack your compiler or something.

Answer (score 1):

It is my experience that "forcing" programmers to use something only inhibits their thought process and causes resentment to grow throughout the group.

Comment: We understand that, but they do miss a lot of things and causes us lot of problems with this call. So we have written our own method and we must ensure they use this.

Comment: Your answer confirms your age. At 22 I probably felt the same way. So forcing programming to adhere to processes, best practices and team standards causes resentment to grow? Any team that has this problem needs to grow up a bit and shed the 'wild west' mentality of software development.

Comment: If that's the case, I say that you should do a better job of hiring competent programmers or be better at teaching them proper technique.  I for one would never want to work with someone who doesn't trust me and would rather modify the .NET framework than to show me proper ways of doing things.

Comment: Hire better, more honest programmers. Or - do it yourself. You shouldn't have the power to modify the .net framework

Comment: @Randy - If anything, my age only further illustrates the need to properly teach me rather than to modify the .net framework.  What message are you sending to someone when you force them to use something different rather than sitting them down and teaching them proper technique?  I may be young and not as experienced as you, but I certainly know that this is not the proper way to go about things.

Comment: We do trust our programmers, but this is a specific situation. I don't want to restrict no-one using a better way, I just want to restrict Parse(). They can still use ParseExact().

Answer (score 1):

We've started using [FXCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9AEAA970-F281-4FB0-ABA1-D59D7ED09772&displaylang=en) and, speaking as a developer, it's not so bad.  It should be able to easily block the usage of certain methods.

Comment: Oops.  I didn't see Nick's answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299851/how-to-block-usage-of-datetime-parse-from-coders-on-visualstudio-project/2299955#2299955

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing code reviews, which you should be, you can catch it during the review. Otherwise, there is no way to prevent someone from calling a static method in the .NET Framework (that I'm aware of).

Comment: We want to force them to use something else.